# How to pass "settable at queue time" variable value from build pipeline to release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have two pipelines on azure devops that do the following:

**BUILD PIPELINE**

- Asks the user for the desire branch name and ticket id (from our ticketing system). Using two "settable at queue time" variables.
- Gets the files from the specified branch name, builds the project and generate the artifacts that are later use by the RELEASE pipeline

**RELEASE PIPELINE**

This release pipeline is being triggered by the completion of the BUILD pipeline specified before. This pipeline completes the following tasks:

- Creates new app service slot using an Azure CLI command task. In this task I need the ticket id, in order to create the slot with the corresponding ticket id as its name
- Deploy the application to the created app service slot

I haven't found a way to pass to the RELEASE pipeline the ticket id the user entered when running the BUILD pipeline that triggered this RELEASE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTS : Can I access the Build variables from Release definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905024/vsts-can-i-access-the-build-variables-from-release-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such a build-in function in Azure DevOps. While thanks to Martin Hinshelwood, we had an extension- [Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration) to achieve the goal.

As you can see in the [extension's doc](https://dev.azure.com/nkdagility/Azure-DevOps-Variable-Tools/_wiki/wikis/variable-tools/14/index), add a **Variable Save Task** in your build pipeline and a **Variable Load Task** in your release pipeline. After these two tasks, the variables are fully passed to your release.

Check below as reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yang; this were really helpful. It is wroking as expected.

Comment: Although this is a very useful extension, the lack of proper documentation is quite infuriating. Do we need to create a Variable explicitly in the Variables section of the build and release pipelines before that can be accessed by the Load and Save tasks?